Is getting home just before Tzeit Kochavim considered Shabbos violation?
If one arrives home during Bein Hashmashot, what is the din - is Shabbat violated or is it bedieved ok (not ideal but ok after the fact)? If violation, is it a d'Rabbanan (Rabbinic transgression) or d'Oraita (Torah transgression)? In this case, I carried groceries from my automobile into my house while there was still a bit of light on erev Shabbos. I know I was later than candle-lighting time but I could not see any stars in the sky at that time. Hope this helps.

Rambam Hilchot Shabbat 5:4:

The time from sunset until the appearance of three middle-sized stars is universally referred to as beyn hash'mashot. There is a doubt whether this time is considered as part of the day or as part of the night. [Accordingly,] it is accepted to rule stringently concerning [this time] in all places. Therefore, one should not kindle [a lamp at this time]. A person who performs a [forbidden] labor beyn hash'mashot [both] on the Sabbath eve and on Saturday night is required to bring a sin offering.
(Touger translation)

The time period of bein hashemashot on Friday evening is treated as doubtfully shabbat. Therefore, as it may be shabbat, one is forbidden to perform any (biblically forbidden) melachot during that time period.
The precise start and end points of bein hashemashot are the subject of a significant amount of debate.

Why do you say "Therefore, as it may be shabbat, one is forbidden to perform any (biblically forbidden) melachot during that time period." Rather than simply: "Therefore, as it may be shabbat, one is forbidden to perform any melachot during that time period." See for example https://outorah.org/p/47194/ "According to the Mishnah Berurah, this dispute remains unresolved and one must accept the stringencies of both views. That means that on Friday evening one must desist from all weekday activities yet before sunset"

@EdwardB There are circumstances under which one may perform actions during bein hashemashot, which would be forbidden once it gets fully dark and is definitely shabbat. See Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 261:1
